# Parsing combinatorial emojis

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, emoji

I have a database full of messages and I'm trying to see each user's most used emojis.

I found [this regex](https://medium.com/reactnative/emojis-in-javascript-f693d0eb79fb), which is "heavily inspired by [lodash’s implementation of split.](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.16.6/lodash.js)"

```
let regex = new RegExp([
    '(?:[\\u2700-\\u27bf]|(?:\\ud83c[\\udde6-\\uddff]){2}|',
    '[\\ud800-\\udbff][\\udc00-\\udfff]|[\\u0023-\\u0039]\\ufe0f?\\u20e3|',
    '\\u3299|\\u3297|\\u303d|\\u3030|\\u24c2|\\ud83c[\\udd70-\\udd71]|',
    '\\ud83c[\\udd7e-\\udd7f]|\\ud83c\\udd8e|\\ud83c[\\udd91-\\udd9a]|',
    '\\ud83c[\\udde6-\\uddff]|[\\ud83c[\\ude01-\\ude02]|\\ud83c\\ude1a|',
    '\\ud83c\\ude2f|[\\ud83c[\\ude32-\\ude3a]|[\\ud83c[\\ude50-\\ude51]|',
    '\\u203c|\\u2049|[\\u25aa-\\u25ab]|\\u25b6|\\u25c0|[\\u25fb-\\u25fe]|',
    '\\u00a9|\\u00ae|\\u2122|\\u2139|\\ud83c\\udc04|[\\u2600-\\u26FF]|',
    '\\u2b05|\\u2b06|\\u2b07|\\u2b1b|\\u2b1c|\\u2b50|\\u2b55|\\u231a|',
    '\\u231b|\\u2328|\\u23cf|[\\u23e9-\\u23f3]|[\\u23f8-\\u23fa]|\\ud83c\\udccf|\\u2934|\\u2935|[\\u2190-\\u21ff])'
].join(''), 'g')
```

So I extract the messages using this query:

```
alltext_query = "select sender, mtext from Messages;"
```

and parse each message like this:

```
pool.query(alltext_query, (err, result) => {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err)
    } else {
        result.rows.forEach(row => {
            console.log(row['mtext'].match(regex))
        })
    }
})
```

This gives me an output like this:

```
[ '', '', '' ]
[ '' ]
[ '', '', '', '', '', '' ]
[ '', '' ]
[ '', '' ]
null # if there's no emoji in the message
```

This is perfect for finding the most used emoji. However, for emojis that have skin tone and/or gender, the output becomes like this:

```
[ '', '', '', '♀' ]
[ '', '♂' ]
[ '', '', '', '', '', '' ]
```

As you can see, the skin color and gender have been separated, which is not desirable.

For the above three arrays, I expected the output to be like this:

```
[ '', '‍♀️' ]
[ '‍♂️' ]
[ '', '', '' ]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: @Emma It's not just ‍♀️ and the like. A lot of emojis are like this; Some of them have gender, some of them have skin color, and some of them have both. Manually checking for all of this doesn't seem right to me. I imagine the regex can be modified to handle this.

Comment: https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter

Answer (score 0):

There is a Node module called [Emoji Test Patterns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-test-patterns) which builds emoji regular expression patterns based on the [emoji-test.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/12.0/emoji-test.txt) data file. You may give it a try and see if it fulfills your needs.

Something like this might work:

```
const emojiTestPatterns = require ('emoji-test-patterns');
let regex = new RegExp (emojiTestPatterns["Emoji_Test_All"], 'gu');
// [...]
console.log(row['mtext'].match(regex));
```